# Friends list and friend's profile pictures - Facebook Graph API (in Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, facebook

I am using Swift and I am trying to get my friends list with a graphrequest but unfortunately only "/me/taggable_friends" has worked, and that does not display all of your friends. It seems like there isn't a way to show all of your friends (which makes absolutely no sense to me, I thought that would be a big one) and if I can get it to show all the friends, I want to be able to access their profile picture.

Basically I am trying to make a collection view that is a list of my friends and their pictures.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23417356/facebook-graph-api-v2-0-me-friends-returns-empty-or-only-friends-who-also-u

Answer (score 1):

You should use `/me/friends/`. Starting from v2.0 of the API, it only returns friends who are using your app.

Comment: But that doesn't exists

Comment: @WizKid What do you mean?

Comment: There is no API to get all friends